# Kotlin warning: accessing non-final property in constructor

Tags: kotlin

I have some following code and got a warning for `producer` variable which is `accessing non-final property in constructor`

```
class KafkaService {

  val producer: KafkaProducer<String, String>

  init {
    val props = Properties()
    props[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "127.0.0.1:9092"
    props[ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG] = "DemoProducer"
    props[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java.name
    props[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java.name

    producer = KafkaProducer(props)
  }

  fun sendToKafka(topic: String, message: String) {
    val producerRecord: ProducerRecord<String?, String> = ProducerRecord(topic, null, message)
    producer.send(producerRecord)
  }
}
```

What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: With this code? `producer` isn't `open` and you aren't accessing it, only initializing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should initialize your `producer`variable as lazy:

```
class KafkaService {

  val producer: KafkaProducer<String, String> by lazy {
    val props = Properties()
    props[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "127.0.0.1:9092"
    props[ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG] = "DemoProducer"
    props[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java.name
    props[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java.name

    KafkaProducer(props)
  }

  fun sendToKafka(topic: String, message: String) {
    val producerRecord: ProducerRecord<String?, String> = ProducerRecord(topic, null, message)
    producer.send(producerRecord)
  }
}
```

This way, your variable will be initialized the first time you access it, and you won't be reassigning a final variable.
Give [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) a read for a better understanding.

Comment: is it to possible to modify the code to initialise `KafkaProducer` when the app starts instead of when the first time we access it?

Comment: You could define an `initialize` method and call it in your `Application` class `onCreate` method but, unless the initialization is slow and want to have it preloaded, it wouldn't make any difference than doing it lazy.

Answer (score 0):

`producer` should be made `final` to get rid of this warning. Either with the `final` keyword or by making it private, which would make it implicitly `final`.

NB: In Kotlin `final` is the opposite of `open` and means "cannot be overridden". See [Inheritance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html). For those used to Java, beware that in Java `final` has two distinct meanings:

- "cannot be overridden" (just like in Kotlin),
- but also "is assigned only once" (what Kotlin uses the `val` keyword for).

NB: In Kotlin properties are `final` by default, so something that the OP did not share must be opening `producer`. Maybe the [all-open](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html) compiler plugin.